# cron for rebuild xmlsitemap mannually without drush in cpanel

Tags: cron

I'm using this: **XMLsitemap** module: https://www.drupal.org/project/xmlsitemap

I have a cpanel shared hosting in hostgator and drupal 7. I can not install Drush, ssh access is not enabled. i go to tasks cron in cpanel and setup the cronjob, but in field 'COMMAND' i tried :

```
curl drush xmlsitemap-rebuild http://link.com.br/cron.php?cron_key=xxxxx
```

Nothing , because i dont have a drush installed.
So, i tried:

```
curl xmlsitemap-rebuild http://link.com.br/cron.php?cron_key=xxxxx
```

Nothing too,lastly I used:

```
xmlsitemap-rebuild http://link.com.br/cron.php?cron_key=xxxxx
```

But that is not recognized as Linux command in Terminal .... cron does not happen, what should I do?

EDIT 1:
the task only works if i press the button on image, [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can probably request the the Drupal 7 cronjob by using `wget` or `curl`. On my server I can use: `/usr/bin/wget -O -q /dev/null http://www.example.com/cron.php?cron_key=XXXXX`.

The cron key is different per website and can be found on your status report page.

This basically opens a webpage just as if you would be running cron manually, but you can set an interval for it. If you set xmlsitemap to generate a new sitemap during cron (I believe that is default behavior), you should be good. You can set the rebuild time on the settings tab:
[image: settings tab].

There is no direct need for Drush (though you can do this with Drush as well), and it is not possible to run Drush with curl.

If you or someone else wants to use Drush;
After installing Drush on the system you can use it like any other program: `drush xmlsitemap-rebuild` or `drush @site_alias xmlsitemap-rebuild` if you configured a [site alias](https://www.drupal.org/node/1401522).

Comment: thanks for reply, I tried using wget, curl and as your link tip, but the rebuild of xmpsitemap is only functioning manually , i have edited my question with an image

how do I proceed? thank you

Comment: It works on cron, just not every time. It only rebuilds after the minimum set time has expired. See the screenshot. It has been for working on cron for years now on my website :)